# Can we have a ternary relationship together with a recursive one in E-R diagrams

Tags: database, database-design, modeling, entity, relationships

I am designing an E-R Diagram for a simple system where there are some users and contests. A user can create a contest or invite other users to the contest who can decide to accept or not.

I am wondering if it is possible to model this in an E-R using a recursive diagram since a user can invite an other user mixed together with the contest since the invitation is linked to a certain contest.

Does it make sense? Or what would be the alternatives?

**Image with my E-R:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your model does not correspond to your narrative.  It says:

- A `user` can create a `contest`
- A `user` can invite another `user` to a `contest`.  The inviting user doesn't need to be the creator.  He/she doesn't even be invited him/herself.

If you want that the creator only can invite `users`,  you should make `invitation` a binary relation between `contest` and the invited `user`, being understood that the invting user is the creator of the contest.

Now, if you want that the creator and the already invited users (or a group of responsible users) can send invitations,  you could think of the ternary relation.

Except that [Recursive relationship](https://sielearning.tafensw.edu.au/toolboxes/Database_Administration/content/models/e_r_model_relationships.htm#Recursive%20Relationships) are in principle unary. And ternary relations are making diagrams difficult to read (especially when cardinality is added).  Furthermore, they often reveal themselves as the symptom of a hidden entity. The fact that you name the association `Invitation` rather than `Invite`  only reinforces this impression.

You would significantly increase the clarity of your model with the following alternative:

- An entity `Invitation`
- A relation `invites to` between `Invitation` and `contest`
- A relation `sends` between `User` and `Invitation`
- A relation receives between `User` and `Invitation`